# create macro that will convert excel rows from single sheet to new sheets

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need to create macro that will convert excel rows from single sheet to new sheets.

I have 3 Rows of headers followed by lots of rows of data.

I would like to place each row on this sheet "Dept" into new sheets of their own (with the exception of the header rows).  On each new sheet created, I would like the top 3 rows (the headers) repeated and formatting copied (if possible), then the single corresponding row from the "Dept" sheet.  I would also like the new sheets to be named the value entered in column A (i.e. Ceiling Lights or Wall Lights from the example below).

I have no macro experience, so I'm having trouble taking code from previous answers and trying to apply it to my cause.  Thanks for the help!

```
       A           B           C          D
```

1. dept template // promos       // quicklinks // main banner
2. where found  // content slot  // category  // attributes
3. blank        // content asset // html     //  hero image
4. Ceiling Lights // value  // value // value
5. Wall Lights // value // value // value
6. Floor Lights // value // value // value

Converted to new sheets in the same workbook that have a single row after the 3 header rows:

new sheet named: Ceiling Lights

```
       A           B           C          D
```

1. dept template // promos       // quicklinks // main banner
2. where found  // content slot  // category  // attributes
3. blank        // content asset // html     //  hero image
4. Ceiling Lights // value  // value // value

new sheet named: Wall Lights

```
       A           B           C          D
```

1. dept template // promos       // quicklinks // main banner
2. where found  // content slot  // category  // attributes
3. blank        // content asset // html     //  hero image
4. Wall Lights // value  // value // value

Here's the code I have so far...

```
Sub Addsheets()
Dim cell As Range
Dim b As String
Dim e As String
Dim s As Integer
Sheets("Dept").Select
a = "a4"
e = Range(a).End(xlDown).Address 'get's address of the last used cell
 'loops through cells,creating new sheets and renaming them based on the cell value
For Each cell In Range(a, e)
    s = Sheets.Count
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(s)
    Sheets(s + 1).Name = cell.Value
Next cell

Application.CutCopyMode = True

Dim Counter As Long, i As Long

Counter = Sheets.Count
For i = 1 To Counter
    Sheets("Dept").Cells(1, 3).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheets(i).Cells(1, 3).PasteSpecial

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I can get the new sheets to create and name based on the cells in column A with the top portion of code, but when I tried adding code to have the first three rows (the header rows) copy to each of these newly created sheets I get Error 9 Subscript out of range for:         Sheets(i).Cells(1, 3).PasteSpecial.

Not sure how to fix?
Also, is there a way to preserve the header formatting (column widths)?

Comment: `I need to create macro....I have no macro experience...` Good Place to start with http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010014111.aspx And once you have some code with which you are stuck with then simply post it back :)

Comment: thanks! I deleted what I was working with yesterday because it wasn't working.  But I'll give this tutorial a try and post back here.

Comment: added code to my post!  Any help is MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, tmpSht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    '~~> Change Sheet1 to the sheet which has all the data
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If LastRow < 4 Then Exit Sub

        For i = 4 To LastRow
            If DoesSheetExist(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then
                Set tmpSht = Sheets(.Range("A" & i).Value)
            Else
                Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                Set tmpSht = ActiveSheet
                tmpSht.Name = .Range("A" & i).Value
            End If

            .Rows("1:3").Copy tmpSht.Rows(1)

            For j = 1 To 4
                tmpSht.Columns(j).ColumnWidth = .Columns(j).ColumnWidth
            Next j

            .Rows(i).Copy tmpSht.Rows(4)
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function DoesSheetExist(Sht As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets(ws)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not ws Is Nothing Then DoesSheetExist = True
End Function
```

Comment: Yes! This is SO close. 1. Is there a way for the formatting (specifically the column widths) to also be copied over to the new sheets? 2. This code seems to add sheets to the left of the main sheet and continue adding to the left.  Is it possible to reverse this and have the new sheets added to the right?  Thank you so much! This will save me tons of time.

Comment: I get the error: sub or function not defined and it highlights "DoesSheetExist".  Do I need to enter the sheet name "Dept" in more than one place or just at the top?  Thanks.

Comment: You didn't copy the `Function DoesSheetExist` from the code above?

Comment: Sorry! I pasted it incorrectly.  This absolutely works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user1399767 - Now that you have your solution, please review [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)